# Proper way of truncating a table in Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I can successfully truncate a table like this:

```
Context.Database.SQLQuery("TRUNCATE TABLE [MYTABLE]; SELECT 0");
```

But SQL Server places a lock on the truncated table until the end of the transaction. Therefore, I cannot perform any other operations on the table untli then. How could I resolve this issue?

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem. How long is your transaction? What other operations need to be performed, and on which transaction? Also, since you are not actually performing a query, you can use `ExecuteSqlCommand()` instead of `SQLQuery`.

Comment: Why would you want to perform any other operations on the table before it was completely truncated?

Comment: I agree with William, if your gonna delete everything... you cannot intend to manipulate what your deleting